# Как сделать компоненту прозрачной?

Tags: objective-c, ios

как сделать прозрачной (opacity, transparent) компоненту UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uiview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* view;
...
view.hidden = YES;
```

view станет невидимым и не будет получать события.

Comment: это совсем другое

Answer (score 0):

Ну и последний, 3й вариант

```
UIView* view ...
view.alpha = 0;
```

С этим можно баловаться бесконечно.